# Populate database column with drop-down menu item

Tags: java, oracle-xe

I'm quite new to Apex and Oracle in general, but I would like to know how to populate a database column with the data from
the drop-down list

[Currently I'm not getting further than simply creating the drop-down items](http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=64147:22:146041968480901%3a%3aNO)

What I'm going for is that if the user chooses (e.g.) Company2 and department7 and inserts data into the tabular and pushes submit, then the Company data would populate the company column in the db;  dep would populate department column and same principle for other drop-down items)